# How to show list from json in react with props

Tags: reactjs, arrays, json, react-props

I'm trying to show data from a json file using react, but I want the list within a key value pair to also be displayed as a list. However I'm getting stuck as to whether I need to map my props or after. Below is my code of what I have tried so far.

I want to show the subjects list from this json file:

```
    [
  {
    "id": 145,
    "title": "Middlemarch",
    "authors": [
      {
        "name": "Eliot, George",
        "birth_year": 1819,
        "death_year": 1880
      }
    ],
    "translators": [],
    "subjects": [
      "Bildungsromans",
      "City and town life -- Fiction",
      "Didactic fiction",
      "Domestic fiction",
      "England -- Fiction",
      "Love stories",
      "Married people -- Fiction",
      "Young women -- Fiction"
    ],
    "bookshelves": ["Best Books Ever Listings", "Historical Fiction"],
    "languages": ["en"],
    "copyright": false,
    "media_type": "Text",
    "formats": {
      "application/x-mobipocket-ebook": "https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/145.kf8.images",
      "application/epub+zip": "https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/145.epub3.images",
      "text/html": "https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/145.html.images",
      "application/octet-stream": "https://www.gutenberg.org/files/145/145-0.zip",
      "text/plain": "https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/145.txt.utf-8",
      "image/jpeg": "https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/145/pg145.cover.medium.jpg",
      "text/plain; charset=us-ascii": "https://www.gutenberg.org/files/145/145-0.txt",
      "application/rdf+xml": "https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/145.rdf"
    },
    "download_count": 165079
  },
```

This is my props from one page:

```
<Typography id="spring-modal-title" variant="h5" component="h2">
          Title: {props.title}
        </Typography>
        <Typography id="spring-modal-title" variant="h5" component="h2">
          Author: {props.author}
        </Typography>
        <Typography id="spring-modal-title" variant="h6" component="h2">
          Language: {props.language}
        </Typography>
        <Typography id="spring-modal-description" sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
          <ul>
          Genre: {props.subjects}
          </ul>
        </Typography>
```

And this is where I am trying to map through the list for each array within my json file:

```
 <BookModal 
                title={book.title}
                author={book.authors[0].name}
                subjects={[book.subjects].map((s)=>(
                  <li>s</li>
                ))}
                language={languageAbbr[book.languages]??book.languages}
                description= {book.title}
                />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this code:

```
<Typography id="spring-modal-description" sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
          <ul>
          Genre: {props.subjects}
          </ul>
        </Typography>
```

With this code:

```
<Typography id="spring-modal-description" sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
  <ul>
    Genres:
    {props.subjects.map((subject, index) => (
      <li key={index}>{subject}</li>
    ))}
  </ul>
</Typography>
```

And to pass the subjects list to your BookModal component, you can simply pass the book.subjects array directly:

```
<BookModal 
  title={book.title}
  author={book.authors[0].name}
  subjects={book.subjects}
  language={languageAbbr[book.languages] ?? book.languages}
  description={book.title}
/>
```